# How can I disable keybindings CTRL+Grave (CTRL+Tilde, CTRL+`) on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: keyboard, 15.04, shortcuts, shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and they changed a hotkey.

Is there a way to turn off the system's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>? It shows a popup in the top right about connection settings, and I do not want this.

I use hotkeys in several applications, but I can't figure out where to find this one. I can't find it in the keyboard bindings.

- Tried finding in Compiz Config Settings Manager
- Tried `gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more` but it doesn't show.

All that pops up is this at the top right:

[image: connection established popup]

Answer (score 10):

That is actually [dunst](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dunst) notifier.
You could disable this shortcut by copying `/etc/xdg/dunst/dunstrc` to `~/.config/dunst/` and commenting out line 
`history = ctrl+grave`
in shortcuts section

Comment: Works! Don't forget to reboot to apply this change.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to
 System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Find the shortcut you're trying to disable
click on it to set a new shortcut
Press Backspace to disable that shortcut

Comment: Hey I have looked in here for CTRL+` but I promise I can't find it in there.